# Text file can't be created inside a folder

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, file-manager

I'm trying to create a `log.txt` file inside a folder of a device, but I get this error:

> NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file “log.txt” couldn’t be saved in
> the folder “Logs”.

The folder `Logs` already exists on the device, but I still get this error. Please find my code below:

```
let path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!

let logPath = path.appendingPathComponent("Logs").appendingPathComponent("log.txt")

try! "Hello world".write(to: logPath, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
```

However, if I replace the `logPath` with `path.appendingPathComponent("log.txt")`, it will work, BUT it creates the file outside of the folder `Logs` instead of inside.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What does `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.appendingPathComponent("Logs").path)` return?

Comment: @vadian it returned true

Comment: How did you created the folder ? It may be write protected.

Comment: I fixed this problem using the new function of FileManager api. Please find more detail in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem by using the new function called `appending(component:_)` of the `FileManager` API.

The old one that I used in my question was not deprecated, but it did not work, and I still have no idea.

However, using the new one above makes everything works just fine.